# How to edit a xcmsSet generated by the package XCMS

Tags: r, bioconductor

Due to the XCMS doesn't offer wrapped methods for normalization, I have to do the normalization by my own codes. In purpose of generating normalized Diffreport with diffreport(), I'm trying to edit the xcmsSet. But the code groupval(xset)<- doesn't work. The result is shown below.

Is there any method to edit the groupval of a xcmsSet?

```
> groupval(xset2)<-normalizedValue
   Error in groupval(xset2) <- normalizedValue : 
   could not find function "groupval<-"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [reference manual](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/xcms/man/xcms.pdf) of the package, please notice on page 80 a list of methods available for this class. For `groupval` there is no 'setter' method, only 'getter', meaning you can't set values to the class using `groupval` (in contrast, method `groups` supports assignment). If you want to do something non-standard with the class, you will have to modify each slot manually or write your own method.